# Anaconda-Spyder is not working in Windows 10

Tags: installation, anaconda, spyder

I installed anaconda but after, when I click on the navigator symbol it can not launch anaconda. I tried just click on spyder but it didn't work  either.
I uninstalled and installed a couple of times and tried every solution I found here also. But non of them worked. When I try to open spyder with anaconda prompt, I get following error.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing error: Belirtilen modül bulunamadı.

Can anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Which version of spyder with which python? because spyder has issues with pyqt5 if it doesnot matches, the spyder is not able to work.

Comment: I have downloaded directly from anaconda.com and I didn't make any changes like downloading python or spyder seperately. It downloaded python 3.8 but I dont know what is the spyder version

Comment: try Spyder 3.2.2  with pyqt5==5.11.2 and see if this works.

Comment: You mean, I should type on the anaconda prompt screen? Sorry, I am very new

Comment: No, it is different version from the current one. you have to type >>     pip install Spyder==3.2.2 and than, after this installation  type >>   pip install PyQt5==5.11.2      try these in combination and let me know.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I did all and installed successfully but unfortunately it still doesnt work

Comment: which anaconda package you are using now and python inside?

Comment: it is anaconda 1.7.2 and python 3.8.3

Comment: can you please install https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.07-Windows-x86_64.exe and see if still issue.

Comment: thank you I will try and comment about it as soon as possible

Comment: I have found a proper internet connection and installed but it is still the same. I can not open navigator. I tried to open it as administrator too

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please see [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to understand how to bring Spyder back to life again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open cmd or anaconda prompt,input spyder return ,see what the mistake is . If it is a package version problem, try to uninstall and install the library of the specified version. I encountered a similar problem. I unloaded the library that reported errors. Finally, I reduced the version of pyqt5. Finally, I succeeded